# Dart game Android app and Java server to keep sore

Tags: java, android, java-server

My question isn't necessarily on how to do this - rather I'd really like to know where to start. I've made a program in Java that keeps track of a dart game. I have a core `DartGame` class and classes for the different games that inherit it. From there it keeps track of players, who's turn it is, the current score, etc. It works great now what I want to do is make it into an Android app. I have a server program on my computer that would link the running apps. I don't want a global server that can be accessed anywhere because I don't want to spend the money on a VPN server, so the server program would just run on my PC. An example of a similar type of server would be like the one used for AndroMouse which allows you to control the cursor on a PC with an Android device.

What is the best way to make the connection from the device to the PC? I'm not sure if it uses a MAC address or the WIFI from my router, or even Bluetooth is an option. I'm not really familiar with Android but I assume there would be some sort of Server/ServerSocket connection, but that requires an IP address and I'm not sure which one to use. Is it as simple as using the local IP from my router? Like I said I'll learn how to do it on my own, I'd just like to know what I need to learn before I spend a bunch of money on Android books. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your pc and your device are in the same LAN, just create socket to communicate through wifi connection. Otherwise, you should choose bluetooth I think. I think the

If they are not in the same LAN, then it is a little bit difficult. MAC address is meaningless unless in LAN.

[AndroMouse](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iandrobot.andromouse.lite) also uses bluetooth connection.

Comment: Yeah, its for personal use and really to save some wall space so its all in range of my router. So I would use the local IP to make the `Socket`/`ServerSocket` connection? By local IP I'm referring to my routers IP its something like 192.168.x.x. The only time I've ever tested a program that required a `Socket` connection was a messenger program I made for educational purposes and I just used the localhost, I never used it remotely. So if I'm to use my local IP you're saying treat all devices on the same LAN just as I ran the two programs on my PC's localhost?

Comment: They are actually same, in LAN, using private address like 192.168.*.* is fine.